# How to load SCSS of a component without @import

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I developed a small floating action component. The component consists of a .ts, .html and a .scss-file. At the moment I import the scss file into the app.scss.

Is there a way to load the SCSS automatically when using the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're aware of the `styles` and`styleUrls` properties on [`ComponentMetadata`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html).

AFAIK, you can't pass a raw, uncompiled .scss file in through `styleUrls`, but it's fairly easy to set up your module loader to handle the compilation step for you transparently.

This is particularly true if your module loader is webpack: See [here](https://github.com/RCVSim/client/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js) for one example of a webpack configuration that allows you to add scss files anywhere in your app and then use them [like so](https://github.com/RCVSim/client/blob/94091a62b679c4a33522342ff6b7089b74f8ac99/src/app/components/app.container.ts):

```
@Component( {
  selector     : "app",
  styles       : [ require( './app.scss' ) ],    
  template     : `<route-view></route-view>`,
} )
export class AppContainer {}
```